# Get Barcode 128 encoded text. I want to use a Barcode font to show it, not generate images

Tags: vb.net, barcode

I would like to get a class or function, if possible written in VB.NET, to add it to my projects.
This class or function should be able to receive a text and return it as Barcode 128 encoded text.

I found lot of solutions for generating the barcode images directly, but what I need it's only the part which converts a text to a Standard Code 128 encoded text, then I will show it using a Barcode font.

I also found some codes to do it, but the returned encoded text is not the expected one, because I cannot read it with the Barcode Reader, or sometimes appears a char which cannot be represented by the barcode font.

The encoder should be able to convert this:

> 15868/039

Into this:

> Í/vÈ8/039[Î

As this online converter can do it https://www.bcgen.com/fontencoder/ when you click on the button [Code 128]

Comment: You can find (both free and commercial) Fonts that generate different barcode representations. Code 128 is pretty common, it won't be difficult to find one that works well enough.

Comment: That encoded version probably specific for their 128 font though.. Buy their font, use their encoder for free. They give a .NET DLL: https://www.idautomation.com/font-encoders/

Comment: I have the fonts. Some of them, in fact. The problem is the code to convert an initial text to an encoded text to be represented by the font. The link I provided returns an encoded text which can be represented by the fonts I have, and can be readed by the reader, but they sell the components. I would like to get a free class or funcion which do the right translation. Perhaps anyone can provide a link or sample to test it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I wanted. I'm sharing here the code for those users who has the same problem.

I've translated from C# to VB a Class that I found in Internet (https://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar-en/code128.htm)

It has an "Encode" function which receives the original text and returns the encoded text. It works perfect to be represented by the font Libre Barcode 128 (https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Libre+Barcode+128+Text)

```
'
'Auteur:    Joffrey VERDIER
'Date :     08/2006
'Légal:     OpenSource © 2007 AVRANCHES
'
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Text

Public Class BarCode128

    Public Function Encode(chaine As String) As String

        Dim ind As Integer = 1
        Dim checksum As Integer = 0
        Dim mini As Integer
        Dim dummy As Integer
        Dim tableB As Boolean
        Dim code128 As String
        Dim longueur As Integer

        code128 = ""
        longueur = chaine.Length

        If longueur = 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine("\n chaine vide")
        Else
            For ind = 0 To longueur - 1
                If Asc(chaine(ind)) < 32 Or Asc(chaine(ind)) > 126 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("\n chaine invalide")
                End If
            Next
        End If

        tableB = True
        ind = 0

        While ind < longueur

            If tableB = True Then

                If ind = 0 Or (ind + 3) = longueur - 1 Then
                    mini = 4
                Else
                    mini = 6
                End If
                mini = mini - 1

                If (ind + mini) <= (longueur - 1) Then
                    While mini >= 0

                        If Asc(chaine(ind + mini)) < 48 Or Asc(chaine(ind + mini)) > 57 Then
                            Console.WriteLine("\n exit")
                            Exit While
                        End If
                        mini = mini - 1
                    End While
                End If

                If mini < 0 Then
                    If ind = 0 Then
                        code128 = Char.ToString(Chr(205))
                    Else
                        code128 = code128 & Char.ToString(Chr(199))
                    End If
                    tableB = False
                Else

                    If ind = 0 Then
                        code128 = Char.ToString(Chr(204))
                    End If
                End If

            End If

            If tableB = False Then
                mini = 2
                mini = mini - 1
                If (ind + mini) < longueur Then
                    While mini >= 0
                        If Asc(chaine(ind + mini)) < 48 Or Asc(chaine(ind)) > 57 Then
                            Exit While
                        End If
                        mini = mini - 1
                    End While
                End If
                If mini < 0 Then
                    dummy = Int32.Parse(chaine.Substring(ind, 2))
                    Console.WriteLine("\n  dummy ici : " & dummy)
                    If dummy < 95 Then
                        dummy = dummy + 32
                    Else
                        dummy = dummy + 100
                    End If
                    code128 = code128 & Chr(dummy)
                    ind = ind + 2
                Else
                    code128 = code128 & Char.ToString(Chr(200))
                    tableB = True
                End If
            End If


            If tableB = True Then
                code128 = code128 & chaine(ind)
                ind = ind + 1
            End If

        End While

        For ind = 0 To code128.Length - 1
            dummy = Asc(code128(ind))
            Console.WriteLine("\n  et voila dummy : " & dummy)
            If dummy < 127 Then
                dummy = dummy - 32
            Else
                dummy = dummy - 100
            End If
            If ind = 0 Then
                checksum = dummy
            End If
            checksum = (checksum + (ind) * dummy) Mod 103
        Next

        If checksum < 95 Then
            checksum = checksum + 32
        Else
            checksum = checksum + 100
        End If
        code128 = code128 & Char.ToString(Chr(checksum)) & Char.ToString(Chr(206))

        Return code128

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I frankly do not understand why this was so hard to find, both this post and the solution site, especially because Google and other font sites supply plenty of variants of Code 128 font. I am using this to print labels from the Web App, I really do not need barcode images and associated complexity in the Web scenarios.

Comment: Wonderful! I'm not alone ;-) I also didn't understand why it was difficult to find, since I thought it would be a very easy thing to find. Hope this can help others... Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Not works for me, do you have the updated Code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I made a few changes to this as it would trip up - a few things were missed when checking for non-numeric digits (and the checksum "dummy" wasn't being calculated properly).

```
    Imports System
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Text



    Public Class BarCode128
    Public Function Encode(chaine As String) As String

    Dim ind As Integer = 1
    Dim checksum As Integer = 0
    Dim mini As Integer
    Dim dummy As Integer
    Dim tableB As Boolean
    Dim code128 As String
    Dim longueur As Integer

    code128 = ""
    longueur = chaine.Length

    If longueur = 0 Then

    Else
        For ind = 0 To longueur - 1
            If Asc(chaine(ind)) < 32 Or Asc(chaine(ind)) > 126 Then
                Return chaine
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
    End If

    tableB = True
    ind = 0

    While ind < longueur

        If tableB = True Then

            If ind = 0 Or (ind + 3) = longueur - 1 Then
                mini = 4
            Else
                mini = 6
            End If
            mini = mini - 1

            If (ind + mini) <= (longueur - 1) Then
                While mini >= 0

                    If Asc(chaine(ind + mini)) < 48 Or Asc(chaine(ind + mini)) > 57 Then

                        Exit While
                    End If
                    mini = mini - 1
                End While
            End If

            If mini < 0 Then
                If ind = 0 Then
                    code128 = Char.ToString(Chr(205))
                Else
                    code128 = code128 & Char.ToString(Chr(199))
                End If
                tableB = False
            Else

                If ind = 0 Then
                    code128 = Char.ToString(Chr(204))
                End If
            End If

        End If

        If tableB = False Then
            mini = 2
            mini = mini - 1
            If (ind + mini) < longueur Then

                While mini >= 0

                    If Asc(chaine(ind + mini)) < 48 Or Asc(chaine(ind + mini)) > 57 Then ' THIS WAS NOT CHECKING THE CORRECT SPOT IN THE STRING

                        Exit While
                    End If
                    mini = mini - 1
                End While

            End If

            If mini < 0 Then
                Console.WriteLine(chaine.Substring(ind, 2))
                dummy = Int32.Parse(chaine.Substring(ind, 2))
                Console.WriteLine("\n  dummy ici : " & dummy)
                If dummy < 95 Then
                    dummy = dummy + 32
                Else
                    dummy = dummy + 100
                End If
                code128 = code128 & Chr(dummy)
                ind = ind + 2
            Else
                code128 = code128 & Char.ToString(Chr(200))
                tableB = True
            End If
        End If


        If tableB = True Then
            code128 = code128 & chaine(ind)
            ind = ind + 1
        End If

    End While

    For ind = 0 To code128.Length - 1
        dummy = Asc(code128(ind))  ' ADDED THIS
        Console.WriteLine("\n  et voila dummy : " & dummy)
        If dummy < 127 Then
            dummy = dummy - 32
        Else
            dummy = dummy - 100
        End If
        If ind = 0 Then
            checksum = dummy
        End If
        checksum = (checksum + (ind) * dummy) Mod 103
    Next

    If checksum < 95 Then
        checksum = checksum + 32
    Else
        checksum = checksum + 100
    End If
    code128 = code128 & Char.ToString(Chr(checksum)) & Char.ToString(Chr(206))

    Return code128

End Function
```

Comment: Not works for me, do you have the updated Code?